# How to dynamically hide a RadioGroup

Tags: android

Im dynamically changing a activty so I can use it for 2 diiffrent things, 
If it is being used to buy bitcoins, I would like to be able to hide a RadiGroup.

Comment: did you tried with setVisibility(View.Gone) ? and calling again the references after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the RadioGroup view an ID in the xml file and in the activity find it and set its visibility to GONE when you want to hide it.

Comment: findViewById wont work to get a RadioGroup object.  How do I get the RadioGroup Object so I can chnage it????

Comment: RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);